# React Native with mongdb realm, Realm.App(config) always returns empty object

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform, mongodb-realm

Below is the quick start code to initiate the app given in MongoDB realm docs.

```js
import Realm from 'realm';
    
let app;
    
// Returns the shared instance of the Realm app.
export function getRealmApp() {
    if (app === undefined) {
        const appId = 'demo'; // Set Realm app ID here.
        
        const appConfig = {
            id: appId,
            timeout: 10000,
            app: {
                name: 'demo',
                version: '0',
            },
        };
        
        app = new Realm.App(appConfig);        
    }
    
    return app;
}
```

when I call that function, I always get:

> empty object {}

Version of realm : `"^10.0.0-beta.12"`

Answer (score 3):

Here's my answer [from another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63268611/empty-object-user-when-authenticating-with-realm-credentials-jwttoken-and-real/63361156#63361156). I believe the issue is on their side, not on your side; it's not possible to print objects directly. This isn't limited to the `app` object.

The developers have suggested using `.toJSON()` as a workaround. See [this post from the MongoDB Developer forum.](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/why-the-realm-for-react-native-is-still-beta/8996/4?u=john_saigle)

> I've had some troubles converting any Realm objects to printable
> strings; I always get {} just like you do. I think it could be related
> to this (unresolved) task on their GitHub.
>
> On a similar note, there are some bugs in Realm's authentication
> system. I'm trying to get email/password, Facebook, and Google
> authentication going in my application but all of them currently seem
> to be broken on Realm's side.
>
> Here are some related issues on their GitHub that you can follow for a
> solution.
>
> ```
> Facebook
> Google
> Email/pass (fixed, but not released in the latest beta)
> ```
>
> I don't have any information about JWT specifically but given these
> other authentication issues there's a good chance the issue isn't on
> your side. I recommend opening an Issue on their repository.